# Creating image fade in HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've been playing with HTML `canvas` and recently started changing the opacity of images with `context.globalAlpha`. I thought it would be fun to write a little script to automatically fade an image out. On the left side of the image, `globalAlpha` would be 1 (entirely opaque) and on the rightmost side `globalAlpha` would be 0 (entirely transparent).

I tried taking 1-pixel wide slices of the source image and setting the `globalAlpha` to a gradually decreasing number :

```
fadeCtx = fadeCanvas.getContext('2d');

for (var i = 0; i < sourceImage.width; i++) {
    fadeCtx.globalAlpha = (sourceImage.width - i) / sourceImage.width;
    console.log(fadeCtx.globalAlpha);
    fadeCtx.drawImage(sourceImage, i, 0, i + 1, sourceImage.height, i, 0, i + 1,    sourceImage.height);
}
```

([JSFiddle of my code](http://jsfiddle.net/beej/WHv7t/3/))

But this appears to have no effect. The image is drawn in place, but it is fully opaque throughout.

Am I missing something about how to set opacity? As you can see in the fiddle, I've successfully set `globalAlpha` for an entire image. It's just when I try to draw "image slices" that it appears to have no effect.

Comment: you need to clear the canvas each time you draw a new image. ctx doesnt do it for you for free.

Comment: Didn't realy answer the question and wasn't really helpful... See my solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed it:

http://jsfiddle.net/mattdlockyer/zNcRB/

You were drawing the image over itself using i + 1 as the src image width and dst image width, instead use 1 for both.

The real offender was the dst image width, but I think using 1 for src image width may improve performance.

```
fadeCtx.drawImage(sourceImage, i, 0, 1, sourceImage.height, i, 0, 1, sourceImage.height);
```

Hope this helps!